# SparkJob did not start on kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I started the Spark Job on Kubernetes but failed to start.
The error messages say that there are 3 different logs but I feel hard to solve the reason why the job didn't start. The first message is `org.apache.spark.SparkException: External scheduler cannot be instantiated` and the second message is that `Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [get]  for kind: [Pod]  with name: [spark-steve-test-01-6e0725754f4ca4eb-driver]  in namespace: [spark]  failed.`. I tried to google it but I could not find the proper answer. Finally it was caused by the error saying that `Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc: Temporary failure in name resolution` which is related to the DNS but I didn't pinpoint the reason for it.

Below is the full logs containing the three error messages I indicated.

```
bistel@BISTelResearchDev-NN:~$ kubectl logs spark-steve-test-01-11a02a754f4ad99e-driver --namespace spark
++ id -u
+ myuid=185
++ id -g
+ mygid=0
+ set +e
++ getent passwd 185
+ uidentry=
+ set -e
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ '[' -w /etc/passwd ']'
+ echo '185:x:185:0:anonymous uid:/opt/spark:/bin/false'
+ SPARK_CLASSPATH=':/opt/spark/jars/*'
+ env
+ grep SPARK_JAVA_OPT_
+ sort -t_ -k4 -n
+ sed 's/[^=]*=\(.*\)/\1/g'
+ readarray -t SPARK_EXECUTOR_JAVA_OPTS
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' '' == 2 ']'
+ '[' '' == 3 ']'
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' -z ']'
+ case "$1" in
+ shift 1
+ CMD=("$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit" --conf "spark.driver.bindAddress=$SPARK_DRIVER_BIND_ADDRESS" --deploy-mode client "$@")
+ exec /usr/bin/tini -s -- /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --conf spark.driver.bindAddress=192.168.161.14 --deploy-mode client --properties-file /opt/spark/conf/spark.properties --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.1.jar
20/10/22 07:51:52 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
20/10/22 07:51:52 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 3.0.1
20/10/22 07:51:52 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
20/10/22 07:51:52 INFO ResourceUtils: Resources for spark.driver:

20/10/22 07:51:52 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
20/10/22 07:51:52 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: Spark Pi
20/10/22 07:51:52 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: 185,bistel
20/10/22 07:51:52 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: 185,bistel
20/10/22 07:51:52 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
20/10/22 07:51:52 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
20/10/22 07:51:52 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(185, bistel); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(185, bistel); groups with modify permissions: Set()
20/10/22 07:51:52 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 7078.
20/10/22 07:51:52 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
20/10/22 07:51:53 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
20/10/22 07:51:53 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
20/10/22 07:51:53 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
20/10/22 07:51:53 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMasterHeartbeat
20/10/22 07:51:53 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /var/data/spark-e2826aee-558b-4701-a48a-bc0385788c81/blockmgr-c41d0d9f-13c2-4e94-8074-850ac71bc8c8
20/10/22 07:51:53 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 413.9 MiB
20/10/22 07:51:53 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
20/10/22 07:51:53 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
20/10/22 07:51:53 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://spark-steve-test-01-11a02a754f4ad99e-driver-svc.spark.svc:4040
20/10/22 07:51:53 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.1.jar at file:/opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.1.jar with timestamp 1603353113441
20/10/22 07:51:53 WARN SparkContext: The jar local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.1.jar has been added already. Overwriting of added jars is not supported in the current version.
20/10/22 07:51:53 INFO SparkKubernetesClientFactory: Auto-configuring K8S client using current context from users K8S config file
20/10/22 07:52:14 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: External scheduler cannot be instantiated
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2954)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:533)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2574)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:934)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:928)
        at org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi$.main(SparkPi.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi.main(SparkPi.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:928)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [get]  for kind: [Pod]  with name: [spark-steve-test-01-11a02a754f4ad99e-driver]  in namespace: [spark]  failed.
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:64)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:72)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:225)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:168)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator.$anonfun$driverPod$1(ExecutorPodsAllocator.scala:59)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator.<init>(ExecutorPodsAllocator.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesClusterManager.createSchedulerBackend(KubernetesClusterManager.scala:113)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2948)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc: Temporary failure in name resolution
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
        at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:40)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:185)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:149)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:84)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:215)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:127)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.intercept(BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.java:134)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.ImpersonatorInterceptor.intercept(ImpersonatorInterceptor.java:68)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.lambda$createHttpClient$3(HttpClientUtils.java:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:257)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:93)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:469)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:430)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:395)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:376)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleGet(BaseOperation.java:845)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:214)
        ... 25 more
20/10/22 07:52:14 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://spark-steve-test-01-11a02a754f4ad99e-driver-svc.spark.svc:4040
20/10/22 07:52:14 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
20/10/22 07:52:14 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
20/10/22 07:52:14 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
20/10/22 07:52:14 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
20/10/22 07:52:14 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
20/10/22 07:52:14 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
20/10/22 07:52:14 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: External scheduler cannot be instantiated
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2954)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:533)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2574)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:934)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:928)
        at org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi$.main(SparkPi.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi.main(SparkPi.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:928)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1007)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1016)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [get]  for kind: [Pod]  with name: [spark-steve-test-01-11a02a754f4ad99e-driver]  in namespace: [spark]  failed.
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:64)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:72)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:225)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:168)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator.$anonfun$driverPod$1(ExecutorPodsAllocator.scala:59)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.ExecutorPodsAllocator.<init>(ExecutorPodsAllocator.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.k8s.KubernetesClusterManager.createSchedulerBackend(KubernetesClusterManager.scala:113)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2948)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: kubernetes.default.svc: Temporary failure in name resolution
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
        at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:40)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:185)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:149)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:84)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:215)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:127)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.intercept(BackwardsCompatibilityInterceptor.java:134)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.ImpersonatorInterceptor.intercept(ImpersonatorInterceptor.java:68)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.lambda$createHttpClient$3(HttpClientUtils.java:109)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:257)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:93)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:469)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:430)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:395)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:376)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleGet(BaseOperation.java:845)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:214)
        ... 25 more
20/10/22 07:52:14 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
20/10/22 07:52:14 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /var/data/spark-e2826aee-558b-4701-a48a-bc0385788c81/spark-43b7666c-4762-4347-b6b4-64bf99e509af
20/10/22 07:52:14 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-e0ffc327-1af3-40d5-93d0-a2d541801076
```

My spark script code is as follows.

```
./bin/spark-submit \
        --master k8s://https://192.168.0.91:6443 \
        --deploy-mode cluster \
        --name spark-steve-test-01 \
        --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
        --conf spark.executor.instances=2  \
        --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=spark \
        --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
        --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=sclee01/spark:v2.3.0 \
        --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.limit.cores=4 \
        --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.limit.cores=4 \
        local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.0.1.jar
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you execute `kubectl cluster-info` and paste the output? You should use the Kubernetes master with `k8s://` prefix for `--master`. What's the k8s environment?

Answer (score 0):

Even i had same issue , this answer may help

Initially I created spark Session using this kind of config,

```
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
  .config(sparkConf)
  .master("yarn")
  .appName("Test")
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()
```

due to master yarn it will search yarn in given url , so i changed spark session creation to

```
 val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
  .config(sparkConf)
  .appName("Test")
  .getOrCreate()
```

after this change problem resolved.
you need to see this kind of small configurations.